# How to save images to Render Disk by using Web Service BunJs

Tags: webserver, render, bun

I'm having trouble saving pictures to the Render Disk.

1. I set up the BanJs Web Server on the Render service and opened the Disk with the `/var/lib/data` router
2. Then configured the server and started everything successfully. My app.ts:

```
const STORE_PATH = '/var/lib/data';
const PORT: number = +(process.env.PORT ?? 8080);
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV ?? 'development';

const server = Bun.serve({
  port: PORT,
  async fetch(req) {
    const url = new URL(req.url);
    
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
      return new Response(null, { status: 405 });
    }

    if (!req.body) {
      return new Response(null, { status: 400 });
    }

    const filePath = `${STORE_PATH}/image.jpg`;
    await Bun.write(filePath, await Bun.readableStreamToBlob(req.body));
    return new Response(null, { status: 201 }
  },
  error() {
    return new Response(null, { status: 500 });
  },
});

console.log(`[${NODE_ENV}] Listening on port ${server.port}`);
```

3. When sending a post request with a file via Postman, the server gives status 201 but does not save the file to the Render Disk.

Question: Who has experience in setup, where am I wrong or where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
    import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
    import path, { dirname } from 'path';

    const STORE_PATH = '/var/lib/data';
    const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url); 
    const dirPath = path.resolve(`${dirname(__filename)}/../`);
    
    ...

      const storePath = NODE_ENV === 'development' ? dirPath : STORE_PATH
      const folderPath = `${folderPath}/images`;
      const filePath = `${folderPath}/${name}`;

      const file = await Bun.file(filePath);
      const isFileExists = await file.exists();
            
      if (isFileExists) {
         ...
      } 

      await Bun.write(filePath, image); 

    ...
```

To check if the file exists, you can use the Render terminal and use [SCP](https://docs.render.com/disks#scp) or [Magic Wormhole](https://docs.render.com/disks#magic-wormhole) to check if it is saved correctly.

In order to get the image by Get request, you can use the following code:

```
   const app = new Elysia()
     .get('/images/:imagePath', async ({ params: { imagePath }}) => {
         const storePath = NODE_ENV === 'development' ? dirPath : STORE_PATH
         const folderPath = `${folderPath}/images`;
         const filePath = `${folderPath}/${imagePath}`;
    
         const file = await Bun.file(filePath);
         const isFileExists = await file.exists();
    
         if (isFileExists) {
           return file;
         } else {
           return {
             status: 'failed',
             message: 'File not found',
           };
         }
       }
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. The thing is that `/` is not your root directory.
You can use render's shell to check the path.

Assuming that your project is located under:

```
/opt/render/project/src
```

And your disc is under:

```
/var/lib/data
```

You need to crawl all the way up the path:

```
// assuming your file is in ./src
- const STORE_PATH = '/var/lib/data';
+ const STORE_PATH = '../../../../var/lib/data';
```

I still haven't find a way what path to setup in the view file. If you will, please let me know.

```
<img src="‍♂️"> // ?
```

Comment: Hey. I added my solution, maybe it will be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. That’s what I thought  I went with external service at the end. cloudinary.com